# PHP ImageMagick invert color

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I'm working on a PHP app that converts a self portrait into a pencil drawing and part of the app requires a desaturated/inverted image similar to the example below:

before and after invert:
[image: Before and after invert]

It's easy creating a desaturated image, but how would I achieve this invert using imagemagick? I tried using `negate`, but failed miserably.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 <?php
 $img = new Imagick();
 $img->readImage($image);
 $img->modulateImage(100, 0, 100); 
 $img->writeImage('image.png');
 ob_clean();                         
header('Content-Type: image/png'); 
echo $img;                          
$img->destroy();
 ?>
```

Comment: How was `negate` failing? [Imagick::modulateImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.modulateimage.php) followed by [Imagick::negateImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.negateimage.php) would be a correct method to achieving your task.

Answer (score 0):

According [this](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.negateimage.php) page, you can call imagemagick filter by PHP functions :

```
function negateImage($imagePath, $grayOnly, $channel) {
$imagick = new Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
$imagick->negateImage($grayOnly, $channel);
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

}